# При скроллинге, снизу появляется пустое место. Что делать?

Tags: html, css

https://bluecoc.online/index.html вот сайт, там вы можете ознакомится с кодом для получение информации, мне нужно убрать пустое место при приближении на скриншоте показано как это выглядит, мне уже помогли решить похожую проблему, но теперь мне нужно и тут помощь(я еще зеленый в веб)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что там нет картинки фона

Можно сделать ее позицию фиксированной:

```
.img_1 {
    position: fixed;
}
```